# How use insertRowsAtIndexPaths IOS without reloadData

Tags: ios, uitableview

I don´t understand the `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` use. I need make a `reloadData` of my tableview for this work?

if don´t make a reloadData the application is crashing.

Comment: No you dont have to do reloadData. You need to update your data source array before inserting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The app is crashing because the data source is not consistent before and after the insertRows call.

As an example if you are inserting one new row, you need to return 1 more row in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` than before the insert call.

Here is an example to demonstrate

```
self.numberOfRows = self.numberOfRows + 1;
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are doing, but in short, yes, you need to cause a reload, or an update of your datasource.  Keep in mind, that iOS will only update the data that is displayed on screen, so it will not slow down, or kill your app to do it, if you are dealing with a huge grid.

Comment: But if make a reloadData then all the data is updated and don`t want to do this